# Error: SQL View giving me ORDER BY Error when I try to save it, then it drops WITH statement upon saving. Why?

Tags: sql

I currently have a working SQL view that can query some data from a table.  The data is all in the same table but requires changing columns around to get the right format I need it in.  The code below works as planned when executed.  The problem arises when I try to save the view.  It gives me ORDER BY Clause error " Warning: The ORDER BY clause is used only to determine the rows that are returned by the TOP clause in the view definition..."

If I click ok and save, it will save the view but drop my WITH statement, rendering the code un-executable in SQL server management studio.  Funny thing is, if I connect to the sql view through excel or R, it still runs the code normally and gets me the right data.

Without giving you guys any data, is there something wrong with my syntax that could lead to this?

```
WITH a AS 
(
     SELECT        OrderID, Test, DoneDate AS SampleReceived, row_number() 
     OVER (Partition BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID) AS rn
     FROM            SMSU.DepartmentChain
     WHERE        (Department = 'Sample Receiving')
), 

b AS
(
     SELECT OrderID, DoneDate AS SampleReported, row_number() OVER (Partition 
     BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID) AS rn
     FROM            SMSU.DepartmentChain
     WHERE        (Department = 'Reporting')
)
SELECT  a.OrderID, a.Test, a.SampleReceived, b.SampleReported, a.rn
FROM    a INNER JOIN b ON a.OrderID = b.OrderID AND a.rn = b.rn
WHERE   (a.rn = 1)
```

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: SQL? Is that what you're asking?  I'm connecting to a SQL database through server management studio.

Comment: SQL is a language that most databases understand slightly different dialects of. But what could be useful information here is whether you're using Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, Microsoft SQL Server or some other database product to run your SQL code with.

Comment: Do you need the empty line before `b AS` ? Maybe it's the cause of your problem.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating the view?  If you use a script like so:

```
create view dbo.MyView as 
WITH a AS 
(
     SELECT        OrderID, Test, DoneDate AS SampleReceived, row_number() 
     OVER (Partition BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID) AS rn
     FROM            SMSU.DepartmentChain
     WHERE        (Department = 'Sample Receiving')
), 

b AS
(
     SELECT OrderID, DoneDate AS SampleReported, row_number() OVER (Partition 
     BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID) AS rn
     FROM            SMSU.DepartmentChain
     WHERE        (Department = 'Reporting')
)
SELECT  a.OrderID, a.Test, a.SampleReceived, b.SampleReported, a.rn
FROM    a INNER JOIN b ON a.OrderID = b.OrderID AND a.rn = b.rn
WHERE   (a.rn = 1)
```

It should work.

Comment: I am creating the view inside Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  The weird thing is that the view works as intended, it is only when I go back to the view in the software and the initial with code is gone so I can't execute it within the software.

Comment: What do you mean by "go back to the view in the software"?  Do you mean right click on the view and choose "edit" in management studio?

Comment: Yes, I go back in to edit or design the view and my with statements are gone and I cannot execute.

Comment: For complex views like this one (as opposed to select blah from table), you cannot use the editor.  Instead, right click the view and choose "script as alter" and edit the script.